# all() in empty dictionary returning True and any() returning False

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am getting the following strange behavior when I call all() and any() method over dict.values() in Python:

```
In [34]: empty_dict = {}

In [35]: not_empty_dict = {'a': '', 'b': 'anything'}
```

1 - When I apply `all()` and dict is empty (no keys) Python returns `True`(???):

```
In [36]: all(empty_dict.values())
Out[36]: True
```

2 - when I apply `any()` it returns `False`:

```
In [43]: any(empty_dict.values())
Out[43]: False
```

I just wanted to know the reason for this, can someone explain what's going on?
Using `all()` and `any()` over not_empty_dict will work as expected:

```
In [45]: all(not_empty_dict.values())
Out[45]: False

In [46]: any(not_empty_dict.values())
Out[46]: True
```

Comment: You can workaround this by `if empty_dict and all(empty_dict.values())`. That will return `False` when the collection is empty.

Comment: Why `???`. If there is no counter example, it holds for all. *"All aliens are green"* is obviously true if there are 0 aliens and 0 of them (yup, that's all of them) are green.

Comment: @schwobaseggl It's very well thought out, but it's not obvious, thanks for explaining me

Comment: Now that I read it, the "obviously" sounds fairly arrogant and annoying :D sorry for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` on empty iterables

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)